# JQuery: Add values to append but only if value is not blank

Tags: jquery

I've been working on an experimental wysiwyg interactive web design tool.
Today I decided to implement the ability to have global styles, but I have a bit of a problem....

[image]

Here's a screenshot I took of my application. As you can see there's quite a few values.
There's more to it, but I'm adding the global styles via append. Here's the current code I have of how it's added, but not how it's removed...

```
$(".list-of-css-selectors").append("<div class='list-of-css-selectors-container'><a href='javascript:void(0)' class='del-global-css-style'><span class='fa fa-times'></span></a> <button>"+ $(".add-css-selector-val").val() +"</button>"+ "<pre style='text-align:left; padding-top:5px; overflow:auto;'>"+ $(".add-css-selector-val").val() +" {"+ css attr and values go here +"}\n</pre>" +"</div>");

$(".add-css-selector-val, .custom-css-sheet").val("");
$(".c-css-sheet").html("").html( $(".list-of-css-selectors").html() );
$(".c-css-sheet textarea, .c-css-sheet a, .c-css-sheet button").remove();
$(".custom-css-sheet").val( $('.c-css-sheet').html().replace(/<\/?/g,'').replace(/div class="c-css-sheet hide">/g,'').replace(/div>div class="list-of-css-selectors-container"> pre style="text-align:left; padding-top:5px; overflow:auto;">/g,'').replace(/pre>div>/g,'').replace(/ }div>div class="list-of-css-selectors-container"> pre style="text-align:left; padding-top:5px; overflow:auto;">/g,'').replace(/pre>/g,'').replace(/div>/g,'') );
$(".add-css-refer-val").val("");
FinalizePrev();
```

What I'm trying to do is in position say for example I tell all `.head h1` styles to be positioned relative, top at 1em, and bottom at 1em. I want it to append as.

```
.head h1 {
  position:relative;
  top:1em;
  bottom:1em;
}
```

I've been using the following to check if a value is empty and if it's not I call whatever function the value would be representative for. Here's an example...

```
if ( $(".grab-pos-top").val() === "" ) {
  // do nothing
} else {
  alert("Function called...");
}
```

If I add that within the append function it'd look something like this...

```
$(".list-of-css-selectors").append("<div class='list-of-css-selectors-container'><a href='javascript:void(0)' class='del-global-css-style'><span class='fa fa-times'></span></a> <button>"+ $(".add-css-selector-val").val() +"</button>"+ "<pre style='text-align:left; padding-top:5px; overflow:auto;'>"+ $(".add-css-selector-val").val() +" {"+ if ( $(".grab-pos-top").val() === "" ) { } else { top: value; +"}\n</pre>" +"</div>");
```

The code doesn't do anything and actually shows all my hidden divs, and everything making it look terrible, unusable, let alone making the code itself a headache to edit.

I tried making a variable `GlobalStylez()` a function that renders the same thing, however my problem is getting the value to show as in this case `top:1em;` for example along with the other non empty values.

I apologize for the long question. I asked as simple and thorough as I could related to my problem.

If anyone can help assist me with this problem it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `if` is a statement, you can't use it in an expression. Aren't you getting a syntax error in the Javascript console?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is the conditional operator: `<condition> ? <true-value> : <false-value>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the conditional (aka ternary) operator:

```
$(".list-of-css-selectors").append("<div class='list-of-css-selectors-container'><a href='javascript:void(0)' class='del-global-css-style'><span class='fa fa-times'></span></a> <button>"+ $(".add-css-selector-val").val() +"</button>"+ "<pre style='text-align:left; padding-top:5px; overflow:auto;'>"+ $(".add-css-selector-val").val() +" {"+ ( $(".grab-pos-top").val() === "" ? "" : "{ top:" + value + ";}\n" ) + "</pre>\n</div>");
```

Comment: Thank you. I definitely got some reading to do on conditional/ternary operators.